# How to load product compare,My cart and Newsletter block in front page in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9, mage

I am integrating Custom HTML in my magneto (1.9) and I have to show Product compare,My cart and Newsletter block in front page.

I have configured multi store in it so it is not possible to change in XML file because it reflect other site.So is there any function that directly call respective template file.

[image]

Comment: You can call blocks in home page cms

Comment: How can I call those blocks...? Can I call those in 1cloumn.phtml using conditional statement,it would be good for me.

Comment: You can create different home page for store and add blocks to those.

Comment: I used this Code:


<block  type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter"  template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>

in Layout Update XML of Home page of show newsletter am I right...?
But still block is not seen in front.

Comment: Did you check store dropdown selected?

Comment: Its start working as I cleared the cache...
Thanks for your guidelines,Please tell how to call cart and compare block if you have idea of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98680/discussion-between-disha-v-and-ritesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code in CMS page->Layout update XMl
to get above block.

For Product Compare:-

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

For Recently View:-

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
```

For News letter:-

```
<block  type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter"  template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
```

For My cart:-

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-"/>
```